# Uncaught TypeError: $.getQuery is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code looks like this I have included jQuery and scrollup also and my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            // Parse URL Queries Method
            (function ($) {
                $.getQuery = function (query) {
                    query = query.replace(/[\[]/, '\\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\\]');
                    var expr = '[\\?&]' + query + '=([^&#]*)';
                    var regex = new RegExp(expr);
                    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
                    if (results !== null) {
                        return results[1];
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                };
            })(jQuery);

            $(function () {

                // Change URIs
                $('.pill-switch').click(function () {
                    window.location = '?theme=pill';
                });

                $('.tab-switch').click(function () {
                    window.location = '?theme=tab';
                });

                $('.image-switch').click(function () {
                    window.location = '?theme=image';
                });

                $('.link-switch').click(function () {
                    window.location = '?theme=link';
                });

                // Set theme based on URI
                if ($.getQuery('theme') === 'pill') {
                    $(function () {
                        $.scrollUp({
                            animation: 'fade',
                            activeOverlay: '#00FFFF'
                        });
                    });
                    $('.pill-switch').addClass('active');
                    $('#scrollUpTheme').attr('href', 'css/themes/pill.css?1.1');
                } else if ($.getQuery('theme') === 'link') {
                    $(function () {
                        $.scrollUp({
                            animation: 'fade',
                            activeOverlay: '#00FFFF'
                        });
                    });
                    $('#scrollUpTheme').attr('href', 'css/themes/link.css?1.1');
                    $('.link-switch').addClass('active');
                } else if ($.getQuery('theme') === 'image') {
                    $(function () {
                        $.scrollUp({
                            animation: 'fade',
                            activeOverlay: '#00FFFF',
                            scrollImg: {
                                active: true,
                                type: 'background',
                                src: 'img/top.png'
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    $('#scrollUpTheme').attr('href', 'css/themes/image.css?1.1');
                    $('.image-switch').addClass('active');
                } else {
                    $(function () {
                        $.scrollUp({
                            animation: 'slide',
                            activeOverlay: '#00FFFF'
                        });
                    });
                    $('#scrollUpTheme').attr('href', 'css/themes/tab.css?1.1');
                    $('.tab-switch').addClass('active');
                }

                // Toggle overlay
                $('#toggleActive').click(function () {
                    $('#scrollUp-active').toggle();

                    var text = $(this).text() == 'Hide activeOverlay' ? 'Show activeOverlay' : 'Hide activeOverlay';
                    $(this)
                        .text(text)
                        .toggleClass('active');
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you give more details of issues you are facing

Comment: At what point are you getting that error? Seems to work fine for me in a fiddle, if I remove the scrollUp calls. Why are they wrapped in a `$(function() {});` on their own?

Comment: you must be calling $.getQuery before its added to namespace, please check the order